# Не получается передать List на другую activity через intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Нужно передать на вторую activity List, но, после того как я его записываю в intent и отправляю на другую activity, на вторую activity ничего не приходит...

Класс People

```
abstract public class People implements Parcelable {

private String name, surname;
private int age;

People(String name, String surname, int age) {
    this.setSurname(surname);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return this.getSurname() + " " + this.getName();
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
abstract public String toString();
}
```

Обработчик нажатия на кнопку

```
private List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();
Button btnShowList = findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);
        btnShowList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PeopleListActivity.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) peopleList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Вторая Activity

```
private List<People> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_people_list);

        list = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
    }
```

Ошибки

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                               Process: javalesson.lab2, PID: 5835
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{javalesson.lab2/javalesson.lab2.PeopleListActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class javalesson.lab2.entity.Student
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                    Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class javalesson.lab2.entity.Student
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2304)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1842)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2173)
                                                                       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
                                                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                                                       at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:799)
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:5116)
                                                                       at javalesson.lab2.PeopleListActivity.onCreate(PeopleListActivity.java:19)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    03-18 05:10:46.995 5835-5835/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5835 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете коллекцию обьектов как `parcelableArrayList`.  Но ваш класс `People` не `parcelable`.

Унаследуйте класс от интерфейса `Parcelable` и сделайте как в этом примере.

```
public class FriendDetail implements Parcelable {

    private String full_name;
    private int privacy;

    public HeatFriendDetail(Parcel in) {
        this.full_name = in.readString();
        this.privacy = in.readInt();
    }

    public HeatFriendDetail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(this.full_name);
        dest.writeInt(this.privacy);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public HeatFriendDetail createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new HeatFriendDetail(in);
        }

        public HeatFriendDetail[] newArray(int size) {
            return new HeatFriendDetail[size];
        }
    };

    // GETTER SETTER//
}
```

Источник: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548274/5698345)

Сайт, облегчающий жизнь: [тыц](http://www.parcelabler.com)

Можно еще заюзать GSON и передавать вашу коллекцию как json строку (toJson/fromJson)

Кстати, я бы назвал передачу целого листа из данных не очень удачным решением. `Bundle` при перегрузке может дать исключение. Я считаю, что данные должны грузиться снова, или если они в БД то заново их брать. А вот передавать между активностями можно id нужной записи.

Кстати, зачем вам абстрактный `toString`?

Comment: Про toString. Он переопределяется в дочерних классах.

Comment: Лист заполняется на первой activity и после заполнения всего листа я должен передать лист на другую активность и образам списком

Comment: toString... вы его и так сможете переопределить, это метод класса Object

Comment: просто зачем велосипед абстракции?

Comment: уже исправил, спасибо